# Livewire Quill Editor Image Upload

Tags: laravel-livewire, quill

I'm using Quill editor on Livewire and trying to upload inserted images on editor with [Livewire JavaScript Upload API](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/file-uploads#js-api). The problem is,
I can't insert temporary url to editor. If I use `$image->temporaryUrl()` or `$url` outside of editor, image shows. I can get image temporary url. But `$image->temporaryUrl()` and `$url` not working inside the editor. And images are still uploading to livewire-tmp directory. Just can't insert temporary url to editor.

My blade file:

```
<script>
    var quill = null;

    function selectLocalImage() {
        const input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
        input.click();

        // Listen upload local image and save to server
        input.onchange = () => {
            const file = input.files[0];

            // file type is only image.
            if (/^image\//.test(file.type)) {
                imageHandler(file);
            } else {
                console.warn('You could only upload images.');
            }
        };
    }

    function imageHandler(image) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        var url = '{{ $url }}';
        formData.append('image', image);
        formData.append('_token', '{{ csrf_token() }}');
        formData.append('pageId', '{{ $page->id }}');
        //let file = document.querySelector('image').files[0];
        @this.upload('image', image, (uploadedFilename) => {
            insertToEditor(url, quill);
        })
    }

    function insertToEditor(url, editor) {
        // push image url to rich editor.
        const range = editor.getSelection();
        editor.insertEmbed(range.index, 'image', url);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            modules: {
                syntax: true,
                toolbar: [
                    [{
                        'font': []
                    }, {
                        'size': []
                    }],
                    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
                    [{
                        'color': []
                    }, {
                        'background': []
                    }],
                    [{
                        'script': 'super'
                    }, {
                        'script': 'sub'
                    }],
                    [{
                        'header': '1'
                    }, {
                        'header': '2'
                    }, 'blockquote', 'code-block'],
                    [{
                        'list': 'ordered'
                    }, {
                        'list': 'bullet'
                    }, {
                        'indent': '-1'
                    }, {
                        'indent': '+1'
                    }],
                    ['direction', {
                        'align': []
                    }],
                    ['link', 'image', 'video', 'formula'],
                    ['clean']
                ]
            },
            placeholder: 'Content...',
            theme: 'snow'
        };
        quill = new Quill('#editor', options);

        quill.getModule('toolbar').addHandler('image', () => {
            selectLocalImage();
        });

        quill.on('text-change', function() {
            @this.set('pageBody', quill.root.innerHTML);
        });
    });
</script>
```

My component:

```
public $image;
public $url;
public function updatedImage()
{
    if ($this->image) {
        $this->url = $this->image->temporaryUrl();
        // dd($this->url); <---- Showing temporary url
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

After some research I've changed my code like below.

After upload, fired an event called `imageAdded` with `image` parameter. And listen this event on Livewire component.

With imageAdded function I've defined image's temporary url. And dispatched a browser event called `getUrl`. With `array_push` I added new images to `$images` array. Because there could be multiple images to upload.

Finally, listened dispatched browser event `getUrl` on Java Script and then added to editor with `insertToEditor` function.

```
function imageHandler(image) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', image);
    formData.append('_token', '{{ csrf_token() }}');
    formData.append('pageId', '{{ $page->id }}');
    @this.upload('image', image, (uploadedFilename) => {
        window.livewire.emit('imageAdded', image);
    });
}

window.addEventListener('getUrl', e => {
    e.detail.imageUrl;
    console.log(e.detail.imageUrl);
    insertToEditor(e.detail.imageUrl, quill);
});

function insertToEditor(url, editor) {
    // push image url to rich editor.
    const range = editor.getSelection();
    editor.insertEmbed(range.index, 'image', url);
}
```

Component:

```
public $images = [];
public $image;
public $url;
protected $listeners = ['imageAdded'];

public function imageAdded()
{
    $this->url = $this->image->temporaryUrl();
    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('getUrl', ['imageUrl' => $this->url]);
    array_push($this->images, $this->image);
}

public function store()
{
    foreach ($this->images as $key => $image) {
        $image->store('images/page_images/'.$this->page->id);
    }    
}
```

Now I can upload images with Quill editor on Livewire. Suggestions would be pleased.

Answer (score 0):

I've developed this part based in your code. With that you can replace the temporary url by stored images. If you want, you can save regex in variable.

```
    public function store()
    {
        $this->validate();
        foreach ( $this->images as $key => $image ) {
            
            $temporaryUrl = $image->temporaryUrl();
            preg_match('/(https?:\/\/.*\.(?:png|jpg|gif))/', $temporaryUrl, $tmp);
            if ( $tmp[0] ) {
                $temporaryUrl = $tmp[0];
                $url = $image->store('imgs/help-center');
                $url = config('app.url') . '/' . $url;
                preg_match('/(https?:\/\/.*\.(?:png|jpg|gif))/', $url, $match);
                if ( $match[0] ) {
                    $url = $match[0];
                    $this->article['content'] = str_replace($temporaryUrl, $url, $this->article['content']);
                }
            }
        
        }
        $this->images = [];
        $article = HelpCenter::updateOrCreate([
            'id' => $this->article['id']
        ], $this->article);

    }
```

i hope it help you